# Paginated REST API : How to select amount of data returned?

Tags: rest

I know that from most of today's REST APIs, web calls responses have to be paginated. 
But, I don't see on the web any insight on how to select the ideal size of a batch returned by an API call: should it be 10, 100, 1000. To be short: on what factors should we base the reflection of the size of an API response?

Some people state that it should be based on the number of elements displayed by the UI. I don't agree with this, as not all APIs are directly linked with an UI, and, in any cases, modern REST APIs allow to chose the number of items in output batch with a configurable parameter up to a certain amount.

So, how could we define the value for this "maximum number of elements returned by an HTTP request"? 
Should it be based on the payload size? Internal architecture of the API? Should it be based on performance measurement?

Any insight on this? I'm not really looking for an explicit figure, but more some techniques that could help to find the answer. The best for me would be the process followed by some successful APIs. But, I cannot find any.

Comment: This feels more like a meta question

Comment: How do you select the amount on HTML pages? The same concepts apply to REST as well. Either you are given the options in the responses through link relations and accompanying URIs or a form like media-type that sets some request property. If no option is given by the server the client basically does not have knowledge on how to do it actually unless it has out-of-band knowledge which violates REST principles

Comment: Hi, my question is mainly about having the possibility to offer unknown REST clients to get our data, without any UI (for export or any other kind of purpose), without having prior knowledge of what they will do with it. But, I would like to set up some upper limits on the size of the payload returned based on a reliable procedure.

Answer (score 1):

My general approach to this is to:

1. Try to avoid paging
2. Make REST clients resilient against paging changes, by using `next` and `previous` links, instead of using a `?page=` attribute. A REST client knows another page is available strictly by the appearance of the link.

I don't use hard rules or measurements to figure out when paging is needed. Paging is generally painful, so my first approach would be to try to figure out what requirements drives the need for paging, and if that requirement can be removed.

Once I've determined it's not possible to remove this requirement in another way, I would set the cut-off of a page as large as reasonable, to remove the likelyhood clients need to do additional requests.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. 

But, what about APIs, that are used to export data? 
I mean: let's take stackoverflow has an API to see "my posts". 
I can see posts 10 by 10 on the web, so, the size of the batch should be 10. 

But, shouldn't I provide batches bigger if I want to allow developpers making a full export of their conversations?

Comment: @AlexisClarembeau I think those 2 use-cases are distinct enough, that I would provide 2 api's for them. For the large export, if I assume developers generally want to do a full-export, I would still avoid paging.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a closed API (used only by clients you control), pick whatever the UI wants. It's trivial to change. If clients can choose from several options, you can include a `pageSize` parameter. Or, better..

If it's an open API (used by clients you don't control), then let clients control what size paging they want. Rather than support a `pageNumber` parameter, support `offset` and `limit`. Offset is how many records to skip before starting to return records, and limit is the maximum number of records to return. If the client is not happy with how their request performs, they can adjust the parameters to suit their needs. Any upper limit your API has should be driven by what your service can handle. It's neither possible nor desirable for you to try to figure out the Magic Maximum Page Size that makes all clients happy and no clients sad.

Also, please note that none of this has anything to do with ReST, which is silent when it comes to paging.

Comment: Thanks. 
So, in the case of the open API, you suggest that a client should be able to get 1GB response if they want? 
If not, how can we size the maximum number of records returned. I understand it should be adjustable. But, I don't see how to set the upper limit.

Comment: @AlexisClarembeau If your server can handle it, and they want it, sure. Put a check on the query parameter. If it's bigger than the max you want to support, return a 400 with an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I usually make a rough performance measurement by hand. I want as few requests as necessary, but do not want to risk timeouts.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. Could you add a bit more details about the kind of factors you include in the measurements do you perform? Do you take the point where you are able to serve the most data as possible? In that case, you would end with a very large batch size, which should not fit user isolation needs.